# ddg search error when using fastapi's pip version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, fastapi

I've been trying to get images from duckduckgo using

```
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
from fastcore.all import *

ddgs = DDGS()
def search_images(term, max_images=30):
    print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
    keywords = 'stop sign'
    return L(ddgs.images((keywords, term, max_results=max_images)).itemgot('image'))

but it gives an error:  Cell In[30], line 8
    return L(ddgs.images((keywords, term, max_results=max_images)).itemgot('image'))
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

did some looking up and seems there's some issue with the pip version of fastbook-0.0.16.tar.gz where the file: init.py overwrites and breaks the working version of search_images_ddg
Is there any way to fix this?
If not, is there another search engine API that's good for getting images?
I'm making a basic image recognition thing with fastapi
in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 4):

The images() function of DDGS no longer supports the max_results argument, so we have to do it in a separate step after creating the generator with the images() function.
A generator has no method itemgot(), so we also need to get the urls in another step.

Here is a drop-in replacement for the function search_images based on the current generator implementation of duckduckgo_search.

```py
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
from fastcore.all import *

def search_images(term, max_images=30):
    print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
    with DDGS() as ddgs:
        # generator which yields dicts with:
        # {'title','image','thumbnail','url','height','width','source'}
        search_results = ddgs.images(keywords=term)       
        # grap number of max_images urls
        image_urls = [next(search_results).get("image") for _ in range(max_images)]
        # convert to L (functionally extended list class from fastai)
        return L(image_urls)

# example usage:
urls = search_images("dog images", max_images=10)
print(urls[0])
```

If you have problems with the pip version of fastbook, maybe just install the fastai and duckduckgo_search packages directly.

For installing from a Jupyter Notebook:

```py
%pip install -U fastai duckduckgo_search

# if you use Anaconda locally it is better to use 
# conda or mamba (mambaforge) instead of pip:
!mamba install fastai 
%pip install -U duckduckgo_search 

# or
%conda install fastai
%pip install -U duckduckgo_search
```

Comment: I'm getting a lengthy timeout error message when I try the above.  Perhaps DDG has changed *again* since this was posted? Or perhaps DDG is down today... ?

Comment: @sh37211 have you confirmed that your notebook has internet access enabled? https://forums.fast.ai/t/beginner-using-colab-or-kaggle/96280/7

Comment: @McFizz Turns out that DDG itself was temporarily down for the couple hours I was trying it. Even the DDG CLI scripts would timeout.  Meanwhile I could access any other sites with no problem.  And then later in the day, no problem.  Note too that DDG does enact countermeasures and only the latest duckduckgo_search package will currently work. Earlier versions will return 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the comments in the original notebook to see how other people solved the issue.

[One of them](https://www.kaggle.com/code/jhoward/is-it-a-bird-creating-a-model-from-your-own-data/comments#2575734) changed the *pinned environment* while [the other one](https://www.kaggle.com/code/jhoward/is-it-a-bird-creating-a-model-from-your-own-data/comments#2556645) used a helper function from *fastai* ([which doesn't use the ddg library](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/823b69e00aa1e1c1a45fe88bd346f11e8f89c1ff/utils.py#L45))

Comment: Pinning the environment did the trick for me. Plus I used the replacement function as in @ Jens Wasielewski answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out the function used in the tutorial is outdated, and the updated duckduckgo image() function returns a generator instead of a list, so just changing the function call doesn't solve the problem. What you can do instead is to work around the new function. Try the following:

```
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
from fastcore.all import *

def search_images(term, max_images=30):
    print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
    with DDGS() as ddgs:
        ddgs_images_gen = ddgs.images(term)
        count = 0
        ddgs_images_list = []
        while count < max_images:
            image = next(ddgs_images_gen)
            ddgs_images_list.append(image.get('image'))
            count = count+1
        return ddgs_images_list
```

All the code does is add the desired number of images to a list, then return that list.

```
urls = search_images('stop sign', max_images=1)

urls[0]
```

This should now give the proper result. Hope this helps!

Comment: I needed to change `ddgs.images(term)` to `iter(ddgs.images(term))` in order for the call to `next(ddgs_images_gen)` to work as expected.  Otherwise the above solution worked for me.